# Accessing X with xauth and ssh -X to my VPS?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vps, tunneling, xorg

I have an application I wish to run on my VPS (a web browser actually, iceweasle or similar) and do not really want to install a full blown X server on there for practical reasons.

I have read I only require an X client (both my server and home computer use Ubuntu 10.06, and my server has xauth and sshd and whatnot set up) to run the programs, although with my own home's server.

How would I be able to do this?

I connect to my host with ssh -X foo@myserver although am completely unsure how to access its xauth, do you know of what I can do?

I may settle installing an x server on there to do a VNC instead.. Although it is just not a good idea as I am only occasionally using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssh -Y is what you want to use, you will have to install the package xbase-clients at a minimum (and some font packages), otherwise you'll see an error that the xauth binary doesn't exist.

if xauth is installed, ssh -Y will setup the DISPLAY variable and add the Xauth for you, just start the application.

The other solution is to run a VNC server on it, but doing so is always tricky because for some reason all the VNC packages on ubuntu are just hard to get working right or have weird bugs.

Comment: Thank you, this works excellent and goes well with compression and encryption (-C and -c flags), I was just not sure how it works and opera works fine (Google chrome comes up with profile errors, and firefox doesn't even start, took a long time to fix :P)